# Korean text doesn't show in x-axis label

Tags: r, encoding, ggplot2

I drew a ggplot2 geom_bargraph which x-axis written by Korean.

But these words are broken as you see it below.

[image]

How could I fix this problem?

I use Mac OS X .

Comment: Do you want this graph exported as a pdf, or just viewed in the graph viewer?

Comment: Please add `sessionInfo()` output and ggplot code.

Comment: @sebastian-c I want this graph viewed in the graph viewer and save it as png file.

Comment: sessioninfo : R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] extrafont_0.17      plotly_2.0.16       ggplot2_2.0.0       dplyr_0.4.3         XLConnect_0.2-11   
[6] XLConnectJars_0.2-9

Comment: ggplot(sort.highlight.team, aes(x = team.2, y = mean.champs.organic.reach)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=mean.champs.organic.reach), vjust = 3) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10, family='Arial'))

Comment: That "team.2" is the Korean words

Comment: What might make this easier is making a reproducible example. Try to make a small (3 columns, 5 rows) set of your data in R that shows the problem (maybe a tiny ggplot2 plot with 1 column) and use `dput` to get the structure of the object and post that here.